# Cannot open /dev/console

Tags: c, linux-mint

```
//  console     = fopen("con",  "wt");       this worked under windows
//  console     = fopen("/dev/console",  "wt");     segmentation fault
    console     = fopen("/dev/tty0",  "wt");     returns zero
```

Writing in C, using Mint Linux. I want to talk to the console regardless of redirection of stdin & stdout.

Comment: The closest thing to `"con"` is probably `"/dev/tty"` (not tty0!).

Comment: Maybe write to stderr so that it will show in the terminal even if stdout output is redirected: `"/dev/stderr"`.

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/console` device is not necessarily available to you.  For Linux that device would only show any result if you happen to look at the current virtual terminal.  Also (including Linux), for most systems `/dev/console` requires elevated permissions to open it, e.g., your application is running as `root`.  The reason for that is because some system messages are written to the system console.

For further discussion, here are a few links:

- [Linux: Difference between /dev/console , /dev/tty and /dev/tty0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0)
- [7. Terminal Special Files such as /dev/tty](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html)  from Text-Terminal HOW-TO
- [Understanding /dev](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2597) from Linux Journal