# how to open /dev/console in C

Tags: c, tty

I was reading wayland/weston code, the setting up tty part. I found it tries to acquire an available tty for doing KMS and start windows.

This is how it does:

```
    if (!wl->new_user) {
            wl->tty = STDIN_FILENO;
    } else if (tty) {
            t = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);
            if (t && strcmp(t, tty) == 0)
                    wl->tty = STDIN_FILENO;
            else
                    wl->tty = open(tty, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    } else {
            int tty0 = open("/dev/tty0", O_WRONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
            char filename[16];

            if (tty0 < 0)
                    error(1, errno, "could not open tty0");

            if (ioctl(tty0, VT_OPENQRY, &wl->ttynr) < 0 || wl->ttynr == -1)
                    error(1, errno, "failed to find non-opened console"); 

            snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "/dev/tty%d", wl->ttynr);
            wl->tty = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
            close(tty0);
    }
```

in src/weston-launch.c.

It tries to `open('/dev/tty0')` and find a tty that available if no tty is specified.

But you can't do that, neither `/dev/tty0` nor 'available tty' belongs to you. I tested with my simpler version. And of course I couldn't open `/dev/tty0`.

Do you guys know how this magic is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual *available* devices for a `tty` depend on the system.  On most interactive Unix/Unix-like systems you will have a "tty" whose name can be found from the command-line program `tty`.  For example:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/2
```

Likely, you also have a device *named* "tty", e.g.,

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         26 Feb  9  2014 /dev/tty -> ../devices/pseudo/sy@0:tty
$ ls -lL /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     tty       22,  0 Feb  9  2014 /dev/tty
```

You cannot open just *any* tty device, because most of them are owned by **root** (or other users to which they have been assigned).

For further discussion about the differences between `/dev/console`, `/dev/tty` and other tty-devices, see *[Cannot open /dev/console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444630/cannot-open-dev-console)*.

According to the [console_codes(4)](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_ioctl) manual page:

> VT_OPENQRY
>
> Returns the first available (non-opened) console. argp points to an int which is set to the number of the vt (1 <= *argp <= MAX_NR_CONSOLES).

and for example on a Linux system I see this in `/dev`:

```
crw-rw-rw-   1 root        5,  0 Mon 04:20:13   tty
crw-------   1 root        4,  0 Mon 03:58:52   tty0
crw-------   1 root        4,  1 Mon 04:00:41   tty1  
crw-------   1 tom         4,  2 Mon 04:30:31   tty2
crw-------   1 root        4,  3 Mon 04:00:41   tty3
crw-------   1 root        4,  4 Mon 04:00:41   tty4
crw-------   1 root        4,  5 Mon 04:00:41   tty5
crw-------   1 root        4,  6 Mon 04:00:41   tty6
crw-------   1 root        4,  7 Mon 03:58:52   tty7
crw-------   1 root        4,  8 Mon 03:58:52   tty8
crw-------   1 root        4,  9 Mon 03:58:52   tty9
crw-------   1 root        4, 10 Mon 03:58:52   tty10  
crw-------   1 root        4, 11 Mon 03:58:52   tty11
```

All of those `tty` devices except one for which I have opened a console session are owned by **root**.  To be able to log into one, a program such as `getty` acts to temporarily change its ownership.  Doing a `ps` on my machine shows for example

```
root      2977     1  0 04:00 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty1          
root      2978     1  0 04:00 tty2     00:00:00 /bin/login --                   
root      2979     1  0 04:00 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400     tty3          
root      2980     1  0 04:00 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4          
root      2981     1  0 04:00 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5          
root      2982     1  0 04:00 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

Note that `getty` is running as **root**.  That gives it the privilege to change the ownership of the tty device as needed.  That is, while the ioctl *may* identify an unused tty, you need elevated privileges to actually open it. Linux (like any other Unix-like system) does not have a way to provide ensure that one process has truly exclusive access to a terminal.  So it uses the device ownership and permissions to ensure this access.

Comment: But I can get to know a avaliable tty by`ioctl(fd, VT_OPENQRY, &num)`. If I cannot control a terminal, why linux provides this ioctl?

Comment: Any tty that you can both read and write to is "available".  The sample code assumes that it is a particular name -- which looks odd, since most systems use at least two characters on the end, not a single one.

Comment: By the way, how can I get to know the current tty in C except  `ttyname(STDIN_FILENO)`

Comment: sorry for misusing "available", I actually meant 'unused by others'.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not the superuser then you should only try to access  `/dev/tty`. That is a special device synonym for whichever tty is controlling the current process.

Comment: yeah, I debug weston's code yesterday, `open('dev/tty0')` never runs. And it failed too if it runs.